# Navigation drawer fragment not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

Hello :) Hope you're having a nice day. As for the question, I've made a navigation drawer and added fragment to one of the items, but clicking on the menu item doesn't show the fragment, the drawer just goes back. Sorry, if there's too much code, just wanted to make sure I won't miss anything :) here is MainActivity.java:

```
package com.UntitledStudios.Xuinator2;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private final static String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.UntitledStudios.Xuinator2";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    int count;

    ImageButton XuinaButton;
    Button ResetButton;
    ImageView MemeCornerAd;
    MediaPlayer Xsound;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        RateUs.app_launched(this);

        Xsound=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.xuina2);
        MemeCornerAd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        MemeCornerAd.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromResources(getResources(), R.drawable.adviewpic));

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("count", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        count = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        TextView XuinaText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.HelloNick));
        XuinaText.setText("" + count);

        ClickActionCounter();

        ResetButtonAction();

        RedirMemeAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        BlankFragment fragment = null;
        if (id == R.id.rate) {
            /*final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // package name of the app
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
            }*/
        } else if (id == R.id.Contact) {

        } else if (id == R.id.AboutUs){
            fragment = new BlankFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromResources(Resources resources, int resImage) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 1;
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resImage, options);
    }

    public void ClickActionCounter(){
        XuinaButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Xuina);

        XuinaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (Xsound.isPlaying()) {
                        Xsound.stop();
                        Xsound.release();
                        Xsound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.xuina2);
                    } Xsound.start();
                } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                final Animation animScale;
                animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim_scale);
                v.startAnimation(animScale);

                count++;
                TextView XuinaText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.HelloNick));
                XuinaText.setText("" + count);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("count", count).apply();
            }

        });
    }

    public void ResetButtonAction(){
        ResetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);

        ResetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        TextView XuinaText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.HelloNick));
                        XuinaText.setText("" + count);
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("count", count).apply();
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Reset Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        // Stuff to do
                    }
                });

                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to reset the number of Xuinas?");
                builder.setTitle("Warning");

                AlertDialog d = builder.create();
                d.show();

            }
        });

    }

    public void RedirMemeAd(){
        MemeCornerAd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://m.facebook.com/findmemecorner"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is BlankFragment.Java:

```
package com.UntitledStudios.Xuinator2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }
}
```

here is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/rateus"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.UntitledStudios.Xuinator2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HelloNick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.306" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Xuina"
        android:layout_width="463dp"
        android:layout_height="169dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/xuinalayer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.738"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ResetButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Reset"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.167"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.982" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="247dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/adviewpic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.675"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/reverse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/REVERSE"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Reverse"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.898" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Reverses"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="X0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.934"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.above_inc.shyam.drawer.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and fragment_blank.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.UntitledStudios.Xuinator2.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: is your fragment in no calling ?

Comment: content_main where you are using this xml layout?

Comment: Content main is the default screen, on which i have the drawer @lib4. Abhishek kumar I don't understand what you mean, i call the fragment in OnNavigationItemSelected

Comment: try with my xml code of fragment @Nick and reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your  fragment_blank.xml :(You can use LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc. except FrameLayout)

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.UntitledStudios.Xuinator2.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you :) And I had different types of layout assigned in main activity:) Thanks One More Time :)

Comment: Welcome @Nick, Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems good. 
Try changing the layout of your fragment

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    text"Hello WOrld"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_social_login"/>
```